# When I am going to fetch table data in a servlet using Hibernate, an exception occurs

Tags: mysql, hibernate, servlets

#### selectStudent servlet

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public SelectStudent() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Configuration cf = new Configuration();
    cf.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

    sf = cf.buildSessionFactory();
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    // rd.include(request, response);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Session s = sf.openSession();
    Object o = s.get(Student.class, 5);// Here I select the 5th record from my table
    Student st1=(Student)o;
    out.println(st1.getId() + "<br>");
    out.println(st1.getName() + "<br>");
    out.println(st1.getEmail() + "<br>");
    out.println(st1.getMarks());
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

#### Student table

```
Id   Name     Email                      Marks
2    bjhbs    nsj                        123
3    hbjhsb   njdkn                       12
5    tofik    tofikstamboli1@gmail.com   123
```

#### Stack trace for the exception

[image]

An error occurs:

> Hibernate: select student0_.Id as Id1_0_0_, student0_.Name as Name2_0_0_, student0_.Email as Email3_0_0_, student0_.Marks as Marks4_0_0_ from Student student0_ where student0_.Id=?
>
> Oct 19, 2017 3:59:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke 
>   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [beans.SelectStudent] in context with path [/CRUD] threw exception 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Well, the stacktrace says it happens on line #59 of the SelectStudent.java - which line is #59 in the code you've pasted?

Comment: out.println(st1.getId()+"<br>");  this is #59 line of SelectStudent.java  i think st1.getId() retrieving null value